# Работа с HTML объектами в Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я считываю все содержимое HTML страницы и отображаю его на ней же после этого. Единственная разница, я хочу изменять некоторые части страницы в скрипте. Так есть код следующий:

```
function getHTML() {
    return "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" + $('html')[0].outerHTML;
}

var page = getHTML();
$(".body-block pre code").text(page);
```

Но я не могу понять как работать с элементами в `page`. То есть к примеру я хочу изменять содержимое `"pre code"` на любой другой текст и даже неодноразово. По нормальному я бы сделал это так:

```
$("pre code").text("Новый текст");
```

Но

```
var page = getHTML();
console.log(page.find("pre code").text());
```

Выдаст ошибку:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: page.find is not a function TypeError:
>   page.find is not a function

HTML в проекте это совершенно любая страница кода, пока что у меня нет ничего кроме базового HTML, я просто тестировал новые идеи:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Tests</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Tests">
  <meta name="author" content="Telion">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css?v=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css?v=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="body-block">
        <pre><code>Hello World!</code></pre>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

В голову лезут только регулярные выражения, но я не хотел бы с ними возиться. Нету ли тут какого-либо лучшего решения этой проблемы? Весь этот код можно хоть полностью переписать если есть удобнее вариант, я пока ничего лучше не придумал...

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский нет проблем, обновил вопрос. `"<!DOCTYPE html>\n"` я добавил что бы код страницы который я дублирую на ней же был полноценным, `.outerHTML`, на сколько я знаю, не достает его и я, что бы не заморачиваться, просто вручную его дописал. Весь этот скрипт чисто для красоты и интереса, у меня бывают идеи и постраннее =)

Comment: Могу что-то напутать, но... надо обернуть *page* в `$(page)`. Т.к. *Jquery* при таком синтаксисе создает свой jquery объект, а не просто DOM объект или строку html, с которой ведется работа..... то есть должно быть `$(page).find("pre code").text()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ахах, все было так просто! Перенесите это в ответ я поставлю галочку, спасибо.

Comment: Да можете сами написать ответ и через два дня (из-за таймаута) его принять. Это не возбраняется ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в общем это и не ответ, а лишь половина его(наверное). Я как побежал проверять сразу все так и вспомнил. Могу ли я как-то заменить данные в этом `page`? Например `$(page).find("pre code").text("New Text!");`. Этот код почему-то вообще ничего не делает. Но это и была суть вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем оказалось что можно клонировать обьекты, что оказалось довольно удобно и просто. Следующий код решил мою проблему:

```
originalPage = $("html").clone();
$(originalPage).find("pre code").text("New Text!");
```